# When trying to register a Swing button with an event handler why do I get an error?

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to create a simple Java Swing application that will allow me to simply convert kilometers to miles. When registering a button to an event handler I get an error. The error lies within the textField identifier. There is a red squiggly line that is highlighted underneath and I do not know why it is an error. Here is the code. Much appreciated.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Graphics
    {
    public static void main(String[] args)
        {
    // Create a window
    JFrame window = new JFrame();
    window.setTitle("Distance Converter");
    window.setSize(550, 450);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);

    // Create a panel
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    // Create components
    JLabel message = new JLabel("Enter distance in kilometers");
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
    JButton button = new JButton("Calculate");

    // Add the components to the panel
    panel.add(message);
    panel.add(textField);
    panel.add(button);

    // Add the panel to the window
    window.add(panel);
}

// Add action listener to button
MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener();
button.@addActionListener(listener);


// Register an event listener to the calculate button
private class MyButtonListener implements ActionListener
{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        final double converstion = 0.6214;
        String input; // To hold the user's input
        double miles; // To hold the number of miles

        // Get the text entered by the user into the text field
        input = textField.getText();
        // textField is underlined with red: There is an error here.
        // I do not understand why there is an error here.

        // Convert the input to miles
        miles = Double.parseDouble(input) * converstion;

        // Display the result.

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, input + " kilometers is " + miles + " miles.");

    }
}
}
```

Comment: `button.@addActionListener`?? Why are you using `@`? That's not Java, and the squiggly lines should clue you in to look at the line more carefully.

Comment: Also you look to be trying to call a method outside of a constructor or method, something not allowed if you're not also declaring and assigning to a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can't write statements (method calls, variable assignments et.c) outside of a method or static initialiser. The call to `button.addListener()` should be done within a method, such as the main method.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    // Add action listener to button
    MyButtonListener listener = new MyButtonListener();
    button.addActionListener(listener);
    ...
}
```

Also, the `@` symbol shouldn't occur before the method name in a method call. In the future, you should post the error you get and read it, since it will give you a clue as to what the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback but I still don't understand why textField is underlined red.

Comment: @plee We need more info, like the exact line the error is on and where that is in the code you posted.